# Logistic regression coefficient meaning

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I'm trying to write my own logistic regressor (using batch/mini-batch gradient descent) for practice purposes.

I generated a random dataset (see below) with normally distributed inputs, and the output is binary (0,1). I manually used coefficients for the input and was hoping to be able to reproduce them (see below for the code snippet). However, to my surprise, neither my own code, nor sklearn LogisticRegression were able to reproduce the actual numbers (although the sign and order of magnitude are in line). Moreso, the coefficients my algorithm produced are different than the one produced by sklearn.
Am I misinterpreting what the coefficients for a logistic regression are?

I will appreciate any insight into this discrepancy.

Thank you!

edit: I tried using `statsmodels` Logit and got yet a third set of slightly different values for the coefficients

Some more info that might be relevant:
I wrote a linear regressor using an almost identical code and it worked perfectly, so I am fairly confident this is not a problem in the code. Also my regressor actually outperformed the sklearn one on the training set, and they have the exact same accuracy on the test set, so I have no reason to believe the regressors are wrong.

Code snippets for the generation of the dataset:

```
o1 = 2
o2 = -3
x[:,1]=np.random.rand(size)*2
x[:,2]=np.random.rand(size)*3
y = np.vectorize(sigmoid)(x[:,1]*o1+x[:,2]*o2 + np.random.normal(size=size))
```

so as can be seen, input coefficients are +2 and -3 (intercept 0); 
sklearn coefficients were ~2.8 and ~-4.8; 
my coefficients were ~1.7 and ~-2.6

and of the regressor (the most relevant parts of it):

```
for j in range(bin_size):
    xs = x[i]
    y_real = y[i]
    z = np.dot(self.coeff,xs)
    h = sigmoid(z)
    dc+= (h-y_real)*xs
self.coeff-= dc * (learning_rate/n)
```

Comment: size was 1,000 when I posted the question, but I now tried 10,000 and I obtain essentially the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was the intercept learned? It really should not be a surprise, as your `y` is polynomial of 3rd degree, while your model has only two coefficients, while 3 + y-intercept would be needed to model the response variable from predictors.

Furthermore, values may be different due to SGD for example.

Not really sure, but the coefficients could be different and return correct y for finite set of points. What are the metrics on each model? Do those differ?

Comment: The intercept learnt was in the order of 0.1 (plus or minus, a bit different every time I randomize the input). I suspect that this is the key to the discrepancy, but I'm not sure.
my y has 2 degrees, the x0 is equal to 1 and the theta0 was set to 0 (I should have mentioned that.. sorry).
I tried with SGD and with Batch and after convergence, got about the same results.
Lastly, I was using all the default inputs for sklearn and statsmodels, I'll have to dig a bit deeper to see if that's the key.
Anyway, thanks!

Comment: You can try normal equation with np.linalg.inv and see coefficients, just to be sure and rule out iterative approach failing. Furthermore check predictions and whether regularization was used in statsmodels and/or sklearn.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, they do implement regularization, but even when I turned it off, I got different results.
I guess your initial suggestion is right -= different coefficients can still return correct y values.

Comment: You might be better off on math stackexchange, guys there are more math-oriented and may provide additional insight.